# Insert 1 record to database but 2 column not null - Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, postman

I have filled all required fields in `db.Blog.create` but when i using Postman, the `title` field and `categoryId` field are not recognized.I also tried inserting other fields into the database but it didn't work. Please help mee.
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1uY0.png)
[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTVUk.png)
[Migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNPQf.png)
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj5HE.png)

I want to add data to columns

Comment: Please don't use images as show code, insert code as formatted text blocks in the post. Also please show the controller code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.